# Is a Self-similar Impossible Rod Possible?

Tags: geometry, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

Are there $p_0, q_0 \in\mathbb{R}$, and computable functions $P(p_n, \ldots) = p_{n+1}, Q(q_n, \ldots) = q_{n+1}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $p_n\ge1$, $q_n\ge1$, both $p_n, q_n$ are bounded, and $p_{n+1} + q_{n+1} = 2q_n - 2.5$? (EDIT: the limit condition is wrong, sorry).

The ellipsis in the functions means that these extra parameters maybe included: $q_n$ for $P$, $p_n$ for $Q$, $n$ itself, $w$, etc. I need guidance on how to proceed on problems like this. Thanks!

**Context:** I attempted to create a self-similar impossible rod. Unfortunately, it is not truly self-similar—see the image below.
[image: Image of impossible rod]

As also shown in the image, $p$ and $q$ are proportions to the "width" $w$ of the "outer" and "triangular" part of rod, respectively. For each iteration $n$, this width decreases by half. The relationship between the previous and next iterate gives the $p_n + q_n \ldots$ equation above.

Therefore, answering the above question answers the title question. Here's the HTML code to generate the above image: https://github.com/poypoyan/canvas-svg-experiments/blob/main/impossible-rod/impossible-rod.html.

Comment: Taking the limit on the relation $p_n+q_n=2q_n-2.5$ gives $0=-2.5$.

Comment: You're correct. Apologies. Before reading your comment, I realized that the limit condition is not what I wanted, because $p$ and $q$ are "ratios", not the length themselves.

Comment: The key relation tells us $q_n=p_n+2.5$, so bounding $p_n$ below by $1$, and above by *something*, already guarantees the corresponding conditions on $q_n$. Moreover, $$q_{n+1}=p_{n+1}+2.5=P(p_n)+2.5=P(q_n-2.5)+2.5$$ so the $Q$ function is merely a modified $P$ function. It's pretty easy to give recursions that fit: eg, $p_{n+1}=a+b\sin(p_n)$ for any constants $a$ and $b$ with $a-b\geq 1$. This example doesn't seem suited to an impossible rod construction, however, so your formulation still needs a bit of tweaking. Keep at it! The idea is interesting. :)

Comment: I feel stupid right now, simply because of another silly mistake (this time due to different notation between my sketches and here): the relation should be $q_{n+1} + p_{n+1}=\ldots$. But I think can get ideas from your comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, and the solution is so trivial I should have solved this earlier. The simplest solution is by setting $p_n=3.5$ and $q_n=6$ for all $n$. Both are greater than 1, both are of course bounded, and $6+3.5 = 2(6)-2.5 \implies 9.5 = 12-2.5 \implies 9.5=9.5$.

Here's the rendering for this (10 iterations). Enjoy!
[image: Self-similar Impossible Rod]